# how to get a specific div using jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

i've a problem with selecting a specific child by order , for exemple looking at this html code :

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <div class="partA">
        1
        </div>
        <div class="partB">
        2
        </div>
        <div class="partC">
        3
        </div>
        <div class="partB">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div class = "sublassB"> 5 </div>
        </div>

        <div class="partD">
        5
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

i want using jsoup , get the fourth div for example (body/div[4]/div[5]) , and then get the class name of the fourth div .

i used :eq(n) but it didnt give me the disered result . is there any other way ? 
thanks in advance :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting elements with classname is always preferred but still if you want to go by index numbering you can use below code , you must know exact index you want to fetch though

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.codeinventory.com").get();
Elements body= doc.select("body").get(0);
Elements  div = body.select("div").get(3).select("div").get(4); // here just append select("div").get(n) fi you know exact nesting and div number you want 

System.out.println(div.attr("class")) // this will give you classname
```

Comment: but in case of a long path like this

Comment: /div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[18]/div[2]

Comment: Updated answer! :)

Comment: but in my case i want a dynamic way to solve it , in case of a long path that not containing only div , sometimes other tag . here i found the big problem

Comment: In that case you can use same code in method and call it recursively ;), you need to write that logic if you have dynamic requirement but base of logic remains same as mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to write the path `body/div[4]/div[5]` as a CSS selector:

```
body > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(5)
```

If you use a long path not containing only div or sometimes other tag, simply generate a string on the fly and pass it to Jsoup.